# ProgressBar во время загрузки файла из webView

Tags: android, android-fragment, download, android-webview

Существует андроид приложение с 3мя фрагментами. На одном из них есть вебвью.
 Идея в том, что пользователь скачивает DOCX файл и далее главный фрагмент обрабатывает его. Вопрос, Как показать пользователю прогресс скачки файла?
Вот код фрагмента с WebView

```
private WebView webView;

public String filenameFromWeb;

Intent toInfoClass;







private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);


    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // allow pinch to zooom
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); // disable the default zoom controls on the page








    webView.loadUrl("http://www.permaviat.ru/raspisanie-zamen/");
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            //Checking runtime permission for devices above Marshmallow.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                    downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);



                } else {

                    Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                    //requesting permissions.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);


                }
            } else {
                //Code for devices below API 23 or Marshmallow
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);

            }
        }
    });




    return view;
}

public void downloadDialog(final String url,final String userAgent,String contentDisposition,String mimetype) {
    //getting filename from url.
    filenameFromWeb = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
    //alertdialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //title of alertdialog
    builder.setTitle("Загрузка");
    //message of alertdialog
    builder.setMessage("Вы хотите сохранить " + filenameFromWeb);//Имя файла расписания

    //if Yes button clicks.
    builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (filenameFromWeb.endsWith("docx")) {


                System.out.println("Загрузка");
                //DownloadManager.Request created with url.
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                //cookie
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                //Add cookie and User-Agent to request
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                //file scanned by MediaScannar
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                //Download is visible and its progress, after completion too.
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                //DownloadManager created

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                //Saving files in Download folder
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filenameFromWeb);

                //download enqued
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Мы работаем только с форматом docx",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //cancel the dialog if Cancel clicks
            dialog.cancel();
        }

    });
    //alertdialog shows.
    builder.create().show();




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я у себя использую так. Код на Kotlin.

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
        progressVisible.set(newProgress < 100)
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
    }
}
```

Код на Java:

```
        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            Boolean progressVisible = newProgress < 100;
        }
    });
```